# Read file in line chunks endlessly

Tags: node.js

I am using a +58k list of words to create a web surfing bot. The bot must load 10 lines from a text file containing the list of words, use each of the 10 words in a Google query and then move those 10 words to the bottom of the word list. This is so that if I stop the program halfway through, it will not lose it's place in the word list. This also enables the program to loop through the +58k words endlessly.

So the steps are:

1. Take 10 words out of the file completely
2. Loop through the 10 words doing a Google query with
   each
3. Append the 10 words to the bottom of the word list
4. Take next 10 words
5. and so on and so forth

   ```
   var main = function (browser) {   

   var stream;

   stream = fs.createReadStream('words.txt');

   var chunk = lazy(stream)
       .lines
       .take(10)
       .join(es.mapSync(function (line) {
           stream.pause();
           myFunction(line.toString()).then(() => stream.resume()); <-- One line at a time function           
       }))
       .join(fs.createWriteStream('words.txt'))
       .on('error', function (err) {
           console.log('Error while reading file.', err);
       })
       .on('end', function () {
           console.log('Read entire file.')
           browser.close();
       });
   ```

   }

Comment: So the file grows infinitely large?  What makes the process ever stop?  What is the actual reason for this (I'm wondering if there's a better way to approach it)?

Comment: Nope, **CUT** the lines from the top and append them to the bottom. Basically infinitely looping through the file but this way the program will pick up from the last word it processed before stopping.

Comment: You can't CUT lines from a file.  Modern file systems don't work that way, unless you rewrite the entire file every time you want to cut lines from the beginning of the file.  What problem are you really trying to solve here?  It sure seems like there would be a more efficient way to do this (perhaps with a queue) if we knew what the overall problem actually was.

Comment: I'm using the list of words with [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) to create a web surfing bot. The bot googles "What is " + word and selects a random hyperlink from the results, then scrolls to the bottom of the result page. After which it jumps back to Google with the next word. I want it to run overnight and I will manually stop it in the morning. But when I run it again it must pick up where it left off instead of starting from the first word again

Comment: What does any of that have to do with a file that you're cutting from?

Comment: The file contains the words that I am using in the "What is " + word part. Let me update the question

Comment: You could just have a side configuration file (it could be a JSON file) that contains the file position of the next line to read and then you never have to write to the file at all.  You just rotate through the file reading the next words.  When you shut-down and restart, the side configuration file contains the file position of the next line to read and you start there.  That's tons more efficient than rewriting the entire file everytime you want to remove some lines from the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a scheme similar to what I outlined in my comments.  It offers a function called `readWords()` that takes three arguments:

```
readWords(wordsFilename, numWordsToRead, callback)

    wordsFilename  - filename containing words, one per line
    numWordsToRead - how many words to read in succession each time function is called
    callback       - callback called with each word as a single argument.  
                     The callback can optionally return a promise and readWord 
                     will wait for that promise before proceeding.  
                     If you want to abort processing, you can return a rejected promise.

    The readWords() function returns a promise that rejects if any errors.

    The "state" of where it was reading is saved in a .json file.  That file is whatever
    filename is passed in + ".json".  So, if the passed in filename is "./words.txt",
    then, the json file will be "./words.txt.json".

    Each time readWords is called, it reads the state from words.txt.json and picks up
    in words.txt where it left off last.  It is circular so if it gets to the end of 
    the words.txt file, it will pick up again at the beginning and just keep going
    until it returns the passed in number of words.
```

This code is runnable in node.js all by itself.  All you need is a text file containing words, one per line, that you pass the filename to.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;

async function readWords(filename, numToRead, callback) {
    let startCntr = 0;
    let jsonFilename = filename + ".json";

    try {
        let jsonData = await fsp.readFile(jsonFilename);
        let data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
        startCntr = data.cntr;
    } catch(e) {
        // file didn't exist so ignore the error
    }
    let wordsRead = 0;
    let done = false;
    let processing = false;

    do {
        let cntr = 0;
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
          input: fs.createReadStream(filename),
          crlfDelay: Infinity
        });

        for await (const line of rl) {
            // skip words until we get to our target starting place
            ++cntr;
            if (!processing && cntr <= startCntr) {
                continue;
            }
            await callback(line);
            processing = true;          // flag that tells us whether to examine startCntr or not
            ++wordsRead;
            if (wordsRead === numToRead) {
                let data = {cntr: cntr};
                await fsp.writeFile(jsonFilename, JSON.stringify(data));
                done = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        await rl.close();
        // if we're not done yet, then start over back at the beginning of the file
    } while (!done);
    return done;
}

// example usage    
readWords("./words.txt", 10, function(word) {
    console.log(word);      // will get called with 10 consecutive words
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here
    console.log(err);
});
```